# Как скрыть скроллбар но сохранить скролл страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При нажатии на треугольник появляется список и из-за этого увеличивается высота страницы и появляется скролл. Как убрать скролл со страницы и добавить его внутрь дива для появления этого скролла при необходимости в нем.
skrinshoter.ru/s/301018/oCrvTSZ3?refresh=10

Comment: Прикрепите ваш код в коротком варианте

Comment: Это каким образом делается, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Нашла решение. Необходимо прописать в базовых свойствах:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-color: rgba($color_darkblue, 0.2)
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgba($color_darkblue, 0.8)
}
```